# How do I locate my VS2013 about update 4

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Problem:
How do I review my VS 2013 if I have update 4? I do not know how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: How about "Help | About Microsoft Visual Studio"?

Comment: Can't find it in help > about

Comment: In my VS 2013 Community Edition it sits top left in the second line: "Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4".

Answer (score 1):

Go to Help-->About and then you can find it as in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Where can I download Update 4. I need it

Comment: Go to **TOOLS-->Extensions and Updates...**, and on the dialog opened choose **Updates-->Product Updates** and you should be able to see it in the list.